# Как удалить внутри скобок указанный символ c помощью регулярных выражений php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь удалить все "-", внутри скобок. Пример входных данных:

```
   ZIBERT Lagerbier (Світле), Фастів, Київ -11/4.4 (було- 11.5/4.9)  (пл. 0,5 1,0  1,25 2,0  2,5 бан. 0,5 - експорт )  +Р
```

Моё регулярка не помогает, подскажите что делаю не так. Пример кода:

```
     $string = preg_replace('/(\(.+(-).+\))+/', '', $input_data) ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, `preg_replace` заменяет целиком всё найденное совпадение. Таким образом, ваша регулярка удалит минус вместе со скобками и всем содержимым. Для подавления этого эффекта можно либо выделить части, которые не надо менять, в отдельные круглые скобки и в строке замены возвращать из обратно в виде `$1`, `$2`... Либо использовать выражение `\K` для обозначения места, с которого считать совпадение, и поставить его прямо перед `-`.

Во-вторых, как только замена один раз произойдёт, следующая замена начнёт выполнять выражение с самого начала и будет искать следующую открывающуюся скобку. Чтобы избавиться от этого эффекта, надо применить выражение `\G`, которое заставит работать оставшуюся часть регулярки с места последней замены. Дополнительно надо указать, что `\G` НЕ в самом начале строки, выглядит это как `(?!^)\G`.

В итоге надо искать символ `-` после открывающейся скобки, после которой идёт любое количество символов "НЕ закрывающая скобка" ИЛИ с точки последней замены.

```
$str="ZIBERT Lagerbier (Світле), Фастів, Київ -11/4.4 (було- 11.5/4.9)  (пл. 0,5 1,0  1,25 2,0  -2,5 бан. 0,5 - експорт )  +Р ";
print preg_replace('/(\(|(?!^)\G)[^)]*?\K-/','',$str);
```

Comment: Работает даже: http://ideone.com/Q9qmED

Comment: Оптимальный вариант. Благодарю

Answer (score 3):

Проще искать все подстроки в скобках и у них вырезать `-`.

```
<?php
$str = '   ZIBERT Lagerbier (Світле), Фастів, Київ -11/4.4 (було- 11.5/4.9)  (пл. 0,5 1,0  1,25 2,0  -2,5 бан. 0,5 - експорт )  +Р  ';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\([^)]+\)/', function($match){
    return str_replace('-', '', $match[0]);
}, $str);

var_dump($str);
// string(154) "   ZIBERT Lagerbier (Світле), Фастів, Київ -11/4.4 (було 11.5/4.9)  (пл. 0,5 1,0  1,25 2,0  2,5 бан. 0,5  експорт )  +Р  "
```

[Пример работы](http://ideone.com/pYVFq4).

Comment: Благодарю, работает, но выбираю оптимальное решение.